# FireFox continues to redirect based on outdated httpd.conf rules (other browsers dont)

Tags: firefox, browser, opendns, httpd, mod-rewrite

This is really odd, because it shouldn't be happening at all.

When I access wellness.learnitlive.com on FireFox, I see it redirected to: http://www.learnitlive.com/classes-events/Health-Wellness/280.html

When I access wellness.learnitlive.com on IE/Chrome/Safari/Opera, I see it redirected to: http://www.learnitlive.com/wellness.php

Both are from the same machine. I'm not having FF use any proxy. Moreover, I see the same results on someone else's machine as well.

The  /classes-events/Health-Wellness/280.html redirection was specified in the httpd.conf file yesterday, but is now set to /wellness.php and the httpd server has been restarted several times since the change.

I'm not sure why FF would be behaving like this.

I'm using OpenDNS and have refreshed their cache as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox is caching this resource. Clean your browser cache: **Firefox -> Options -> Privacy -> Clear your recent history -> Tick checkbox for "Cache" -> OK**. Plain and simple.

For completeness, I'll also add that if you want to force a non-cached version of a page to be displayed, using Ctrl+F5 in most browsers will force one. In the case of redirect issues however (such as the one here), this won't help.

Comment: Interesting! And weird! Thanks gman - any thoughts on how I can 'break that'?

Comment: I'm using mod_pagespeed on this server, but that didnt help in this case.

Comment: Browsers cache content for faster page load times. Clearing your cache when doing web development/deployment is just a part of life.

Comment: @SidB: It's not weird if the module is using [301 "Moved Permanently"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.2) type redirects; those are not only *supposed to be cached*, but the browser is even *allowed to update bookmarks and links* based on 301. If you want temporary redirects, switch to 302 "Found" or 307 "Moved Temporarily".

Answer (score 2):

You could change your cache settings so that it checks for a new version of the page every time for all websites.

1. Type into the address bar: **about:config**.
2. Click to confirm that you want to edit the settings.
3. Search for **browser.cache.check_doc_frequency**.
4. Double-click the line.
5. Change the value from 3 (default) to **1**.

For more details on this setting, see this [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency)

Comment: Nice answer. thx for the link